# How to cut off text that is longer than the space available and show '...'?

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have a title of video that is a long title and I would like to display this in a single line like this:

Title: TxT TxT TxT ...

But is displaying like this for now:

Title: TxT TxT TxT TxT TxT TxT
       TxT TxT TxT TxT TxT TxT

here is a Div code

```
<div class="vid-title"><%# Eval("Title")%></div>
```

and her is a css:

```
.vid-title {
  font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; margin: 0px;
}
```

I would like the text to cut off when there is no more space, and show '...' at the end. How to achieve this?

Comment: to the downvoters: what's wrong with this question such that it deserves a downvote? It's verbose and not exceptionally well formulated but it describes a very legitimate problem. Sometimes it's just hard to describe a problem if you don't know the correct terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
div {
    width: 120px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    color: red;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zWvMH/389/)

Comment: in which browser and version are you testing it?